# React Native use Twitter search API with Application-only authentication

Tags: react-native, twitter, oauth-2.0

I am new to React Native and want to build an App that uses the Twitter search API to display Tweets. No need for User Authentication.

I've been struggling the last two nights to get this working and starting to get frustrated xD.

I've tried building the request using Fetch and XMLHttpRequest with no luck. Also I tried several packages enabling OAuth 2.0 which also didn't work. I have the feeling I'm over complicating things as all I want to do is use the Application-only authentication and use the Standard search API.

Does anyone out there please have a code snippet on how to do this in react native without any extra packages? Is it possible at all with "just" Fetch or XMLHttpRequest?

Thanks in advance

Edit: Here's my code so far

```
var base64 = require('base-64');

var credentials = encodeURIComponent(key) + ":" + encodeURIComponent(secret);
var encoded = new Buffer(credentials).toString('base64');
console.log(encoded);

fetch('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded
  },
  body: {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
  },
}).then((response) => console.log(response))
```

Here the response:

```
Response {
   "_bodyBlob": Blob {
 "_data": Object {
   "blobId": "8dea4e53-7b39-4b78-b1a5-d7ef5a58de48",
   "offset": 0,
   "size": 114,
 },
   },
   "_bodyInit": Blob {
 "_data": Object {
   "blobId": "8dea4e53-7b39-4b78-b1a5-d7ef5a58de48",
   "offset": 0,
   "size": 114,
 },
   },
    "headers": Headers {
 "map": Object {
   "cache-control": Array [
     "public, max-age=0",
   ],
   "content-disposition": Array [
     "attachment; filename=json.json",
   ],
   "content-type": Array [
     "application/json;charset=utf-8",
   ],
   "date": Array [
     "Wed, 16 May 2018 16:55:48 GMT",
   ],
   "expires": Array [
     "Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT",
   ],
   "last-modified": Array [
     "Wed, 16 May 2018 16:55:48 GMT",
   ],
   "ml": Array [
     "A",
   ],
   "server": Array [
     "tsa_o",
   ],
   "status": Array [
     "403 Forbidden",
   ],
   "strict-transport-security": Array [
     "max-age=631138519",
   ],
   "x-connection-hash": Array [
     "b6dde5b876b934c8dcdb059ef0c400fa",
   ],
   "x-content-type-options": Array [
     "nosniff",
   ],
   "x-frame-options": Array [
     "DENY",
   ],
   "x-response-time": Array [
     "105",
   ],
   "x-transaction": Array [
     "0084737c0054c4dc",
   ],
   "x-tsa-request-body-time": Array [
     "26",
   ],
   "x-twitter-response-tags": Array [
     "BouncerCompliant",
   ],
   "x-ua-compatible": Array [
     "IE=edge,chrome=1",
   ],
   "x-xss-protection": Array [
     "1; mode=block; report=https://twitter.com/i/xss_report",
   ],
 },
    },
   "ok": false,
   "status": 403,
    "statusText": undefined,
   "type": "default",
   "url": "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for.bumping this but I'm still looking for a solution to this. Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm happy to report I got this working.
Main problem was the encoding of the Request Body.

Here"s the working code to authenticate and get a bearer token. Then using this token to use the search API:

```
_getBearer = () => {

var details = {
  'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
};

var formBody = [];
for (var property in details) {
  var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
  var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
  formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
}
formBody = formBody.join("&");

var key = "xxx";
var secret = "yyy";
var base64 = require('base-64');
var credentials = encodeURIComponent(key) + ":" + encodeURIComponent(secret);
var encoded = new Buffer(credentials).toString('base64');
console.log("Created encoded credentials: " + encoded);
fetch('https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + encoded
  },
  body: formBody
}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) => {
    bearerToken = responseData.access_token;
    console.log("Got Bearer: " + responseData.access_token);
    this._loadTweet();

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    Alert.alert('Alert Title failure' + JSON.stringify(error))
  });

_loadTweet = () => {
  console.log("start load tweet");

  fetch('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=love', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "Bearer " + bearerToken
    }
  }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(responseData));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      Alert.alert('Alert Title failure' + JSON.stringify(error))
    });
};
```

};